# log4j2 not picking up new values for Syslog Appender from MDC

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I have configured log4j2 using following:

```
<Routing name="RoutingRemote">
    <Routes pattern="$${ctx:syslogAdded}">
        <Route key="true">
             <Syslog name="syslog-${ctx:host}" format="${ctx:logFormat}" 
              host="${ctx:host}" port="${ctx:port}"
              protocol="${ctx:protocol}" appName="appname" 
              mdcId="mdc-id"  />
        </Route>

    </Routes>
</Routing>
```

I have the option in backend to update the Syslog server's details, like IP, port, log format, protocol.

The issue I am facing is, when I add values for Syslog, log4j2 always keeps the initial values which I entered the first time and pushes the logs to syslog server which I entered first time.
I checked using debugging that new values are being put in MDC but not getting reflected to log4j2.
This same setup worked for logback but now I need to use log4j2.
what can be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

`MDC` is used for storing information thread-wise and printing that information in log messages.

But, here, you are using `MDC` for appender initialization which is not a good and recommended approach.

In a normal scenario, appenders are initialized during the start of the application. So, in this case, appender is also initialized at the start of the application and then you are putting some values using `MDC` so if you want to use those values, you have to reinitialize log4j2 configuration.

After putting values in `MDC`, add below line of code to reinitialize log4j -

```
((org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false)).reconfigure();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I have already tried this approach but in that case, I don't get any logs after the first time. My use case is that on every new request I have to read values from some object and decide Syslog's attributes.

Comment: You want to change appender configuration for each request. But, appenders are not used for this purpose. Appenders are kind of static that you define them once and then use them forever in your application lifecycle.

Comment: If you know configuration of all syslog appenders, better you define all syslog appenders with their actual configuation in log4j configuration file and then use routing condition to route your log messages in particular syslog appender

Comment: The use case is such that users will provide the details for Syslog server and users can change those details any number of times.

Comment: The same use case, we had implemented using logback and It was working fine. Now for some reasons we need to use log4j2 and implement same use case.